# What is the point of PassportJS - Local Strategy?

Tags: node.js, authentication, passport.js, passport-local

Recently I have implemented a login system using Postgres and Nodejs. It was working properly before I use passport-local. However almost all tutorials I have found online used and suggested using passport, that I did use as well, just in case.

I understand passport would be quite practical for facebook logins etc. However, I do not fully understand the necessity of passport-local strategy. How does it improve my already working login system?

Comment: It does not improve your already existing login system. Instead it could replace it entirely. At least for simple use cases.

Comment: But then I do not see the point since I still have to implement database operations myself(since passport is not db specific). My server code is actually a bit longer now that I added passport-local.